# Get a count of numbers in segments

Tags: c++

The array has a large size up to 100000 and m is number of gets.

For example:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7};

get(1, 4, array);
```

And the result:

```
1: 1
2: 2
3: 1
```

I wrote this but it uses a lot of memory:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    ma[a[i]]++;
    pref[i] = ma;

}
map<int,int> ans = pref[r];
for (auto i: pref[l - 1]) {
    ans[i.first] -= i.second;
}
for (auto i: ans) {
    cout << i.first << ' ' << i.second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If all the numbers are unique, `pref[1]` has one value, `pref[2]` has two,  and so on, and if there are 100,000 unique numbers those maps hold more than five billion values in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is you're computing the answer for all of the numbers. Instead, do this:

```cpp
map<int, int> count(int[] array, int left, int right) {
    map<int, int> result;
    for (int i=left; i <= right; i++) {
        result[array[i]]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's pretty simple; it just iterates over all the indexes and increments the value. Of course, make sure that `left` and `right` are within the bounds of the array.

Comment: thanks but i forget to say i have 1e6 question to get l r

Comment: @Noproblem29 Please explain what you want, as what you said makes no sense.

Comment: i just saying count of function get is 1e6

Comment: What do you mean? Are you calling this `1e6` times?

Comment: yes............